# grep inner working (lines with values given by other file)?

Tags: bash, grep

I found something with grep that works, but am curious to understand why.

I have file1.txt

```
1
2
3
```

and file2.txt

```
1,xx,bb,bb
1,yy,cc,cc
2,xx,dd,dd
2,yy,dd,dd
3,yy,ee,ee
4,aa,ee,ee
5,zz,ee,ee
5,za,ee,ff
x,22,ff,ee
```

Doing `` grep "`cat file1.txt `" file2.txt ``

indeed outputs

```
1,xx,bb,bb
1,yy,cc,cc
2,xx,dd,dd
2,yy,dd,dd
3,yy,ee,ee
x,22,ff,ee
```

But why ? I would have thought the it tries to match the full "string" or exat match to several lines at once.

Pointers to follow up readings are welcome.

Comment: [grep -F](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#grep-Programs) in GNU would cause this behavior. Not sure why it appears to be set by default.

Comment: @BroSlow Maybe it's set as an alias?

Comment: @Ube I have same behavior and `type grep` just returns the binary.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html - a newline is interpreted as delimiter between patterns. When you quote the output of `cat` you preserve the newlines in the file, and each line is searched for as a separate pattern. This appears to work the same way as `grep -f`.

Comment: Do you have leading spaces in each one of the lines of the files?

Comment: @JoshJolly You should post that as an answer. Odd that there is nothing about it in the GNU html manual or man page, but pdf manual includes [Since newline is also
a separator for the list of patterns, there is no way to match newline characters in a text](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.pdf). Not sure what the point of the `-F` option is.

Comment: @fedorqui No leading spaces in the files.

Comment: @JoshJolly Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @BroSlow `-F` also ignores regex characters - eg you can use `grep -F .* f1` to match the literal string `.*` in a file, while without `-F` it will match anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html

> The pattern_list's value shall consist of one or more patterns separated by newlines

So a newline is interpreted as delimiter between patterns, and when you quote the output of `cat`, the newlines within the file are preserved, and grep uses them to separate the file contents into multiple patterns, one per line. This appears to work the same way as using `grep -f`. You can also test this without using cat by adding newlines in your pattern string at the command line:

```
$ grep "patt1
patt2" file.txt
```